# sed does not replace all the matches

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have this on a file:

```
Structural Attributes:    text
                          text_id              [A]
                          text_lleng_tr        [A]
                          text_lleng_or        [A]
                          text_cpr             [A]
                          text_for             [A]
                          text_ftr             [A]
                          text_indexador       [A]
                          text_dif             [A]
                          text_reg             [A]
                          text_esp             [A]
                          text_tem             [A]
                          text_tipus           [A]
                          text_data_or         [A]
                          text_data_tr         [A]
                          text_autor           [A]
                          text_traductor       [A]
                          text_titol_or        [A]
                          text_titol_tr        [A]
                          s
                          s_id                 [A]
                          enty
                          contrac
                          contrac_forma        [A]
                          abr
                          date
                          p
```

Then I run this sed command on it:

```
sed -i "N;s/\[A\]\n/,/g" file
```

From which I get:

```
Structural Attributes:    text
                          text_id              ,                          text_lleng_tr        [A]
                          text_lleng_or        ,                          text_cpr             [A]
                          text_for             ,                          text_ftr             [A]
                          text_indexador       ,                          text_dif             [A]
                          text_reg             ,                          text_esp             [A]
                          text_tem             ,                          text_tipus           [A]
                          text_data_or         ,                          text_data_tr         [A]
                          text_autor           ,                          text_traductor       [A]
                          text_titol_or        ,                          text_titol_tr        [A]
                          s
                          s_id                 [A]
                          enty
                          contrac
                          contrac_forma        ,                          abr
                          date
                          p
```

So, as you can see there still are [A]+line jump left, if I run the sed command a second time on the same file the amount of [A]+line jump decreases, but I have to run the command 3 times for the [A]+line jump to disappear. So the question is, am I doing something wrong or what is the correct way to do it for the [A]+line jump to be replaced at once.

Comment: The N is to act multiline because I actually want to delete the `\n` that comes after the [A]. I have tried the command without the g, but it doesn't help

Comment: Can you please post the final desired output?

Comment: I can suggest a working awk solution if awk is allowed for you. You could post `awk --v`

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful, thanks

Comment: @AndrésChandía, and still posting `awk --v` output would be also desirable

Comment: Yes, of course, then I see how it suits to my needs... thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed`'s not a great tool for that task because it's a line-based text edition tool.

You had to use `N` to consume an additional line so that your working buffer would contain the linefeed separating both lines ; the problem is that this only gives you the ability to work on half the linefeeds each time because once the line is consumed by `N` it won't be consumed by the next pass of `sed` : your first pass replaces the linefeed between `line1\nline2`, then the second pass the one between `line3\nline4`.

One possible solution with `sed` would be to consume the whole file in memory before doing the replacement, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) :

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\[A\]\n/, /g' file
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Comment: That's not a great solution though (especially if your files might get bigger). You might want to wait for another more efficient solution to accept :)